# Regex ignoring the first line in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I need help with optimizing this small system that takes in a string and looks for any words that match the words stored in an array. The system should reprint the same string with the new words every time there was a match. However, it only changes after the first match currently.

Sample text:

`his de is good
but his en is worse then nl`

The result for the above is currently:

```
his Dutch is good
but his English is worse then nl
```

But the result I want to get is:

```
his Dutch is good
but his English is worse then Danish
```

So how can I fix the system to print the second result?

Here is my system in **[JSFIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UYMxa/265/)**.

```
function check(string, wrapper) {
    var terms = ['de', 'en', 'nl'];
    var match = false;

    for(var i=0;i<terms.length && !match;i++) {

        if(string.indexOf(terms[i]) > -1) {
            match = true;
            var newString='';
            wrapper.css("background", "#a1e4ff");
            var matchString = string.substring(string.indexOf(terms[i]), (string.indexOf(terms[i])+terms[i].length));
            var rx = RegExp("\\b" + matchString + "\\b", "g");
            switch(matchString) {
                case 'de':
                newString = string.replace(rx, "Dutch");
                break;
              case 'en':
                newString = string.replace(rx, "English");
                break;
              case 'nl':
                newString = string.replace(rx, "Danish");
                break;
              default:
                alert('no matches');
            }

            $(".corrections").append("<li>" + newString + "</li>");
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('textarea').focusout(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.orig-list').html(x.replace(/\n(?!>)/g, '<li>'));
  });

  $('#down').click(function() {
    $('.orig-list li').each(function() {
        var phrase = $(this).text(); 
        var matchHighlight = $(this);    
        check(phrase, matchHighlight);  
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to add your code, only attaching a jsfiddle is not valid.

Comment: All of my code is in the jsfiddle you can take it from there and this is not a duplicate I spent 2 days looking for an answer but my requirement is very specific. If you know the answer please help

Comment: See http://fiddle.jshell.net/jnyL40nq/1/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I add this in the text area: end is de
I do not get Englishd is German

Comment: Got it: you did not put `<li>` before the *first* item, and that is why you did not select it  (and that is why the string consisting of one line did not work) - see http://fiddle.jshell.net/jnyL40nq/3/ for a fix.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no man that wasn't the issue the issue is that the system doesnt recognize all instances of 'en' and 'de' because if I write in the text area 'end is de' I get asa result: 'end is German' instead of: 'Englishd is German'

see the 'en' instance is not recognized in the word 'end'

Comment: Then remove the word boundaries, `\b`. I thought you did not want to replace `end` with `Englishd`, it does not make sense to me. The code will look like http://fiddle.jshell.net/jnyL40nq/4/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew awesome man thanks so much you deserve a badge, I know it doesnt make sense but I gave that data just as an example my friend my system has more complicated data. I can speak to you about my system privately if you want

Comment: Please check this will resolve your problem http://fiddle.jshell.net/UYMxa/269/

Answer (score 0):

The main point is that you did not add `<li>` tag before the first item, and that is why you `$('.orig-list li').each` did not select it and that is why the string consisting of one line did not work. Change the `$('.orig-list').html()` code to

```
$('.orig-list').html("<li>" + x.replace(/\n(?!>)/g, '<li>'));
```

Besides, it will be much easier if you put the terms with replacements into a dictionary, and use it like

```
if (/en|de|nl/.test(string)) {
        wrapper.css("background", "#a1e4ff");
        newString = string.replace(/en|de|nl/g, function(x) { 
            return terms[x] || ""; 
        });
        $(".corrections").append("<li>" + newString + "</li>");
}
```

See the updated snippet below.

```js
function check(string, wrapper) {
    var terms = {'de':'German', 'en':'English', 'nl':'Dutch'};
    if (/en|de|nl/.test(string)) {
            wrapper.css("background", "#a1e4ff");
            newString = string.replace(/en|de|nl/g, function(x) { 
             return terms[x] || ""; 
            });
            $(".corrections").append("<li>" + newString + "</li>");
        } 
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('textarea').focusout(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.orig-list').html("<li>" + x.replace(/\n(?!>)/g, '<li>'));
  });

  $('#down').click(function() {
    $('.orig-list li').each(function() {
        var phrase = $(this).text(); 
        var matchHighlight = $(this); 
        check(phrase, matchHighlight);  
    });
  });
});
```

```css
span#down {
    background: #4f5152;
    width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.receiver div {
      border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">

  <div class="receiver">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <span id="down">Generate List</span>

   <div>
     <h4>Generated List with unicode errors</h4>
     <ol class="orig-list"></ol>
   </div>

   <div class="corrections-wrapper">
     <h4>Corrected Names</h4>
     <ol class="corrections"></ol>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```